Visual Studio Setup: Linking Azure Dev Ops Project assistance required please?
Hope everyone who is reading this is well.
I have only recently started delving into Azure Dev Ops and I am a bit stuck at the moment.
I have downloaded Visual Studio on my machine and have cloned the repository.
I have made some changes to the files and have committed the changes, however the modified files are not being saved on the Azure Dev Ops side and I am confused as to why this is the case.
Can someone/anyone please assist me with resolving this issue?
Thank you in advance.

Did you push the "Commit All" button, because there is a dropdown next to it where you can choose "Commit All and Push" or "Commit All and Sync"?


I have made some changes to the files and have committed the changes, however the modified files are not being saved on the Azure Dev Ops side and I am confused as to why this is the case.

The commit changes step will save the changed files on your local repo.
To let the modified files to be saved on the Azure DevOps Repo, you need to Push the committed changes to Azure Repo via Visual Studio.
For example:

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Push commit changes

Thank you for the swift response.
I've committed changes a good 30mins, but it still running, the outputs I am getting are as follows:
2024-05-29 08:37:19.184 [info] > git ls-tree -l HEAD -- C:\MyAzureTenant\LCH -AzureProject\outputs.tf [413ms]
2024-05-29 09:56:02.017 [info] > git cat-file -s 382fb5932b6ed573e70a955432a706e45370a6b0 [271ms]
2024-05-29 09:56:11.444 [info] > git show --textconv :.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG [311ms]
2024-05-29 09:56:11.500 [info] > git ls-files --stage -- C:\MyAzureTenant\LCH -AzureProject.git\COMMIT_EDITMSG [346ms]

@LouisA Is your git project large? Or are there a large size of files that have been changed?

Hi Kevin, I have 5 staged changes, nothing too big.

@LouisA In this case, the commit step should not take too much time.

I've reduced it to 1 staged file, still taking a long time.

2024-05-29 11:17:03.412 [info] > git show --textconv :azr-network.tf [536ms]
2024-05-29 11:17:03.490 [info] > git ls-files --stage -- C:\MyAzureTenant\LCH -AzureProject\azr-network.tf [551ms]
2024-05-29 11:17:04.072 [info] > git cat-file -s 46bb890dbeec1b2dc8ae0480a6ee91a3be9bf90a [555ms]
2024-05-29 11:17:04.259 [info] > git show --textconv :.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG [393ms]
2024-05-29 11:17:04.282 [info] > git ls-files --stage -- C:\MyAzureTenant\LCH -AzureProject.git\COMMIT_EDITMSG [391ms]

warning: 2024-05-29 11:16:08.899 [warning] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\MyAzureTenant\LCH -AzureProject.git\refs\remotes\origin\main'

@LouisA can you share the screenshot of the step you commit the changes in VS

Version: 1.89.1 (user setup)
Commit: dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685
Date: 2024-05-07T05:13:33.891Z
Electron: 28.2.8
ElectronBuildId: 27744544
Chromium: 120.0.6099.291
Node.js: 18.18.2
V8: 12.0.267.19-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631

@LouisA When you run the git command on your local machine, can you commit the changes successfully? From the previous info, I haven't see any actual error message.

I've resolved it, was silly, I didn't insert a comment before committing and it was just in an infinite loop @Kevin Lu-MSFT. Thanks for replying to help

@LouisA Glad to know it can work
